# transfer parameter via ajax to php xml by get/post method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

`enter code here`I am try to trnsfer parameter from js to php.
I try to that by ajax and then php need to take the parameter
And export it to xml file not sql so.

I build simle script I am new in js.
my code js:

```
<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="search()" />
```

please enter search word

```
<script>
function search()
{
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        httpObject.open("GET", "search.php?q="+document.getElementById('name').value,  true);
        httpObject.send();
                }   
}
```

phpfile serch.php

```
    <?php
$result_set = $_GET['q'];
echo ($result_set);
?>
```

Thx for any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can save data into an xml file in PHP using SimpleXML.

here's some examples of its use:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Example # 9 shows how to set xml elements, and the other examples deal with various methods of retrieving data.

SimpleXML is easy to use in code, but won't work for very large xml files. for very large xml files you're going to want to use a more advanced parser which doesn't load the entire file at once (instead going line-by-line, saving program memory). These are a bit more difficult, and you can read about one here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/example.xml-structure.php

I would suggest using SimpleXML for now, unless you need to import a very large xml database.

Comment: Ok thx The issue is how I can to transfer parmeter from js ajax to php in this case my parameter is "q" when i try to print echo by php it is not printeted

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, check your spelling and try again.